# Magento 1.9 Rest API

Tags: php, rest, magento, magento-1.9, data-migration

I want to know i there is any way we can bulk create or update products using Magento 1.9 REST API(even if its slow). If yes then how? I have done the connection and authorization, i just need the code for bulk insertion data.
This is my code but its only inserting one product.

```
 $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
    $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
    // get array from db
    include('db-conn.php');
    $select = "SELECT igroup.Igname, item.icode, item.iosunit1, item.israte1, ifvalue.Field3,ifvalue.Field4, ifvalue.Field9, ifvalue.Field1,ifvalue.Field2,ifvalue.Field7, ifvalue.Field8,ifvalue.Field10, ifvalue.Field13, igroup.Magcat FROM tbl_item AS item INNER JOIN tbl_igroup AS igroup ON item.Igroupid = igroup.Igroupid INNER JOIN tbl_ifvalue AS ifvalue ON item.itemid = ifvalue.Itemid  ORDER BY item.Igroupid ASC LIMIT 10";

    $res = mysqli_query($dbconn, $select);
            // set array
    //$proarray = array();

    // look through query
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        // add each row returned into an array

          $proarray= array(
            'type_id'           => 'simple',
            'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
            'sku'               => $row['icode'],
            'weight'            => $row['Field4'],
            'status'            => 1,
            'visibility'        => 4,
            'name'              => $row['Igname'],
            'description'       => 'Simple Description',
            'short_description' => 'Simple Short Description',
            'price'             => $row['iosunit1']* $row['israte1'],
            'tax_class_id'      => 0

        );

          $productData = json_encode($proarray);
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json');
        $oauthClient->fetch($apiUrl.'/products', $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
        // print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());

    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is no REST API product update (on Magento 1.9), but you can use SOAP api, or create your own.

Comment: SOAP API has the functionality of bulk import products? @VasylZhuryk